# Does This Method Have A Name?

Tags: data-mining, pattern-recognition, data-analysis

Not sure if this method exists for data analysis... or even if I can word my question clearly:

If you took multiple transparancies with a map of the world on it, and then placed a 'very light' dot of color at places of interest (one dot on each transparency), when you stacked all of the transparancies on top of each other (in any order really), the 'very light' dots of color would combine to form 'darker' spots indicating increased interest in these locations. Likewise, the 'answer' would become readily apparant just by looking at overlayed maps with little to no calculations

Does this sound like any establised technique that you have heard of? And if so, what is its name?

Comment: It's only an analogy for what might be done mathematically.

Comment: I realized that when I asked the question, and was afraid I wasn't posing my question clearly enough. My mind was thinking of something 'larger' than just counting but couldn't quite grasp it. Or maybe I'm so dumb that I can barely count. :)

Comment: Please remove the hold: i was curious about a methodology to implement through programming, and I heard there were a lot of programmers around here.  One of them might know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

This technique is commonly known as [heat map (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map), and a standard visualization technique.

This is popularly used with [multivariate density estimation (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_kernel_density_estimation).

[image: Picture from Wikipedia]

Picture from Wikipedia, see [File:Old Faithful Geyser KDE with plugin bandwidth.png](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Old_Faithful_Geyser_KDE_with_plugin_bandwidth.png) (CC by-sa-3.0 licensed).

I would not call this "data mining". This is much much older. It's a visualization technique popular in statistics, though; but not so much an "analysis" technique.

Comment: Thank you for providing a mathematical term.  I suppose this is the closest thing to what I am looking for... my hope was that the data could be rearranged such that it would be easier for our brains (using our eyes) to reach a conclusion for something perhaps as complex as a decision tree or something similar.